# Clone a Repo and still get updates from the original source?

Tags: ios, git

We developed a bunch of apps that depend on a single core.

What is the best way to get the core via Git and still get updates if there are bug fixes to the core without my current project specific files to be touched?

Comment: Do you want to PULL updates? Do you have a branch for hot fixes?

Comment: You can get a better answer if you provide more detail on how your core/project repositories are set up.  Unless the real question _is_ how those should be set up.

Comment: Each project consists on it's own. We need to change images, the source data (XML) and make some adjustments on view controller and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each project is just a branch of the "core", and the "core" consists of a set of files not to be customized for each project, then a simple `git remote update; git merge origin/core` (where `origin/core` must point at your core repository) will pull any changes to the core into the project repos.

Comment: Is it possible to have the core project in a seperate repo on the remote and the current project in another repo?

Comment: A remote is, by definition, a "separate repo" :)  Sorry to sound pedantic but these things are easier to understand if terms are used precisely.  So the answer to your question is "yes"

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules)

> It often happens that while working on one project, you need to use
>   another project from within it. Perhaps it’s a library that a third
>   party developed or that you’re developing separately and using in
>   multiple parent projects. A common issue arises in these scenarios:
>   you want to be able to treat the two projects as separate yet still be
>   able to use one from within the other.